# How to use sed to delete multiple lines when the pattern is matched and stop until the first blank line?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am very new to shell script.

How can I delete multiple lines when the pattern is matched and stop deleting until the first blank line is matched?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
sed '/STARTING_PATTERN/,/^$/d' filename
```

This will select all the lines starting from `STARTING_PATTERN` upto a blank line `^$` and then delete those lines.

To edit files in place, use `-i` option.

```
sed -i '/STARTING_PATTER/,/^$/d' filename
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1} /STARTING_PATTERN/{f=0} f{print} !$0{f=1}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, looks like the lines are removed from the output but when I open the file the lines are still there.